# Trying to zoom-in an image in winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms

On button1_Click, I am trying to increase the size of the image by 10 or zooming-in it. But what is happening is that the size of the picturebox is increasing and nothing is happening to the image. How do I  proceed for image zooming. Please suggest me simplest way.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Construct an image object from a file in the local directory.
    // ... This file must exist in the solution.
    Image image = Image.FromFile("Picture1.png");
    // Set the PictureBox image property to this image.
    // ... Then, adjust its height and width properties.
    pictureBox1.Image = image;
    pictureBox1.Height = image.Height;
    pictureBox1.Width = image.Width;
  }
}
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Width += 10;
        pictureBox1.Height +=10;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way that works with what you're trying to achieve is by using the PictureBox's SizeMode property; set it to StretchImage.

[PictureBox.SizeMode Property - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode.aspx)

However, once you're more comfortable with GDI+ (and perhaps even unsafe contexts) you should look at doing this programatically yourself for greater flexibility.